# Using a laptop as a server for Android development in local wifi

Tags: android, xampp, localhost

My laptop and android device are on the same WIFI network. I have localhost on my laptop (XAMPP) and I want to test my app via real device (the emulator working fine with localhost).

I did some googling and found out that I need to pay special attention to the port. So, I changed my http conf from `listen 80` to `listen 8888`. I tried to access `localhost:8888` on my laptop browser and its working fine.

However, I keep getting this exception when trying to access `http://my real IP address:8888/test/index.php` on my android device :

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /my real ip address (port 8888) after 30000ms
```

This is where the exception occured :

```
try{

    URL url = new URL(getUrl);
    //Logr.e("WebGetURL: "+getUrl);
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    if(isJson)
    {
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Expect", "100-continue");
    }
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(30*1000);
    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(timeout*1000);
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

    //urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android; en-us;) AppleWebKit/522+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/419.3");
    //urlConnection.addRequestProperty("http.agent", "Commons-HttpClient/3.1 ()");

    for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry :
        urlConnection.getRequestProperties().entrySet()) {
    }

    OutputStream in = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
    ret = convertStreamToStringOutputStream(urlConnection,in,postData);
    //Logr.d("xx",ret);  
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally {
    //Logr.d("zz", "error, disconnected");
    urlConnection.disconnect();
}
return ret;
```

Comment: Your firewall is probably blocking the connection.

Comment: Use Terminal Emulator for Android to ping your IP. If it responds, then use it in your code.

Comment: @dpsingh i can ping my IP address from the android device...but still my apps throw that exception

Comment: @Squonk Thanks a lot! I need to create an exception both in window's and antivirus's firewall. Link for those who need help : http://www.mobitechie.com/android-2/how-to-access-localhost-on-android-over-wifi/

Please answer my question so i can accept it

Comment: You dont need to change 80 in 8888.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `localhost` or local network `IP address` rather than Global IP address(my IP address).

Comment: localhost is not working, where can i find my local network IP? I used 192.168.bla bla